# python small floats rounding to 2 decimals

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding, precision

Yes, another one of these, however, I have tried a ton of the available examples and solutions and cannot seem to be able to solve my issue.

I need to measure the performance of an API call and decided to use the following:

```
for x in range(0, 5):
    try:
        nf=urllib.urlopen(_url)
        _start=time.time()
        page=nf.read()
        _end=time.time()
        nf.close()
        _delta=(_end - _start)
        _processingTimelist.append(_delta)
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        _processingTimelist.append(9999)
```

outcome:

```
[5.2928924560546875e-05, 4.9114227294921875e-05, 4.887580871582031e-05, 7.510185241699219e-05, 5.1975250244140625e-05]

5.55992126465e-05
```

So far so good, looks like what I'm after. However now I want to submit this to a monitoring service and want to round it to 2 digits, as these are already representing a super small unit (milliseconds) and sending so many digits is just ridiculous.

I have tried a ton of these rounding methods, but I get super strange results like:

```
_processingTime = round(_processingTime, 3)
print _processingTime

result:
0.0
```

OR:

```
_processingTime = float("{0:.4f}".format(_processingTime))
print _processingTime

result:
0.0001
```

Why is that, and how to solve?

I don't care too much about precision, however I would expect for example 5.55992126465e-05 to become 5.56, or even 5.55 would be acceptable as the difference in real time units is super negligible.

Comment: That's not 5.6 milliseconds. That's 5.56 times 10^-5 seconds.

Comment: This is not a programming question... You should read up on [E-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation).

Comment: That's actually 0.000056 seconds. Take note of the `e-05` at the end of your value.

Comment: All those underscores are hurting my eyes!

Comment: Alright, that's clarified now, done some refreshing reading.  I see now how my question is misplaced, as my code behaved as designed, but my brain not. I guess the real question is now how this request could only take 0,056 ms while a simple ping to the same host would take much longer. but I'll guess some reading will enlighten this. Thanks for the replies though!

Comment: I think you need to time *both* the `urlopen` and `read` to get an accurate time. `read` is a bit misleading, since the web response has already been received in its entirety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format your number with scientific notation:

```
>>> '{:.2e}'.format(5.2928924560546875e-05)
'5.29e-05'
```

You can also convert it back into a float:

```
>>> float('{:.2e}'.format(5.2928924560546875e-05))
5.29e-05
```

Or for all your numbers:

```
>>> numbers = [5.2928924560546875e-05, 4.9114227294921875e-05, 4.887580871582031e-05, 
               7.510185241699219e-05, 5.1975250244140625e-05]
>>> [float('{:.2e}'.format(x)) for x in numbers]
[5.29e-05, 4.91e-05, 4.89e-05, 7.51e-05, 5.2e-05]
```

'

Comment: After doing some reading I realise this will be the only ever valid answer to my slightly odd question, even though the results are not what I was looking for.  I do however appreciate the solution and did manage to learn something today, thanks for that!

Comment: You are welcome. Learning something new is the reason to be here after all. :)